# jQuery move div based on child class character length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 4 column template in mobile I want to apply `clear:both` based on child div character length . I mentioned the below the sample code if not clear I will briefly text on commands. Anyone help me to achieve this.

```
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
    <h4 class="tileh4">Rustic</h4>
    <div class="item-wrap">
        <a href="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product_detail/view/YLH6000C">
            <span class="tiadj-img">
                <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-19845.jpg" alt="YLH6000C" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
        <h6>YLH6000C</h6>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
    <h4 class="tileh4">Rusticabcede Rusticabcede</h4>
    <div class="item-wrap">
        <a href="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product_detail/view/YLH6000C">
            <span class="tiadj-img">
                <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-19845.jpg" alt="YLH6000C" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
        <h6>YLH6000C</h6>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
    <h4 class="tileh4">Rusticabc</h4>
    <div class="item-wrap">
        <a href="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product_detail/view/YLH6000C">
            <span class="tiadj-img">
                <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-19845.jpg" alt="YLH6000C" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
        <h6>YLH6000C</h6>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 applyclear">
    <h4 class="tileh4">Rusticabcede</h4>
    <div class="item-wrap">
        <a href="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product_detail/view/YLH6000C">
            <span class="tiadj-img">
                <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-19845.jpg" alt="YLH6000C" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
        </a>
        <h6>YLH6000C</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script I was tried.

```
if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var totLength = $('.tileh4');
            var charLength = totLength.text().length;
            if(charLength > 3){
               totLength.addClass('whitespac');
            }
            $('.applyclear:has(.tileh4.whitespac)').css('clear', 'both');
        });

        }

    else {

        }
```

[sample code here](http://orderonline.my/designer/test/)

Comment: Console shows an error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined" - not necessarily directly related, but it still might stop further script execution. Please fix that, and then do some basic debugging to see whether your code actually runs, and what it does.

Comment: @CBroe I fixed the "Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined" error. but still the same problem.

Comment: Since you have multiple `.tileh4` elements here, you should start by looping over them. Right now you are checking the length of the _combined_ text content of all those elements, and I don’t think that’s what you want.